# Load component in tab template

Tags: tabs, angular, components

I am trying to create an application that has two bottom navigation tabs, and each one will be a different component

This is my code:

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ckAutoLoanCalculator} from '../../components/ckAutoLoanCalculator/ckAutoLoanCalculator';

@Page({
    template: `<ion-navbar *navbar class="contact_navbar">
                    <ion-title>Loan calculator</ion-title>
                </ion-navbar>
                <ion-content><ck-auto-loan-calculator></ck-auto-loan-calculator></ion-content>`,
})
class CompareRates {}

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  directives: [ckAutoLoanCalculator],
})

export class Home {
    loan_calculator: any;
    compare_rates: any;

    constructor() {
        this.loan_calculator = LoanCalculator;
        this.compare_rates = CompareRates;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to load `ck-auto-loan-calculator` component when clicking on the Loan calculator tab .. but it does not load the content, although I can see `<ck-auto-loan-calculator>` inside the content
Do I need to trigger something, or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually `export class CompareRates {}` what I needed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the `import` for your custom tab component.

In Angular2, to pass the class reference to the `directives` property, you need to make it available in that files 'variable scope'

```
import {ckAutoLoanCalculator} from './path/to/component'
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually did imported it, I just forgot to add it in the comment. I edited it now

Answer (score 1):

I would include the `ckAutoLoanCalculator` class into the page that actually uses it, in your case the `CompareRates` one:

```
@Page({
  template: `
    <ion-navbar *navbar class="contact_navbar">
      <ion-title>Loan calculator</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
    <ion-content>
      <ck-auto-loan-calculator></ck-auto-loan-calculator>
    </ion-content>
  `,
  directives: [ckAutoLoanCalculator]
})
class CompareRates {}
```

and not the `Home` one.